# How should we respond to users "reprimanding" other users in comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, etiquette

I recently stumbled across [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378066/is-doom-shroom-worth-its-price#comment531075_378072):

> Aren't you the one who tried posting a answer to my "should I pick doom shroom or cherry bomb" question and got your response deleted? Don't let it happen again!

The answer the comment is referring to is [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378055/73976).

Firstly the answer was actually self-deleted, after 2 downvotes, due to the answer being not the best. But my main issue is the way the user seemed to be reprimanding the poster, as if having an answer deleted by *any* means is not acceptable.

In this specific example, I have flagged their comment, and responded asking them to refrain from this in future. Is this how this sort of thing should be handled?

Comment: D: I didnt even notice that...

Comment: @Eristheguest Good, because you shouldn't have to deal with rudeness like that. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Flagging that comment was the right call.

Beyond that - I would generally discourage any further actions - including leaving comments in reply. Comments are meant for [requesting clarifications or constructive criticism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) aimed at improving the post in question - starting side conversations about someone's tone/rudeness just adds to the noise, and can actually make the situation worse by flaring up more arguments.

Pragmatically speaking, if you **are** going to comment in response, keep it simple, rather than trying to address whatever point they're making. Something like *"Please don't be rude to other users. It might be worth taking a look at Arqade's [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct)"*.

If they come back and continue their rudeness after that, flag and don't respond further - it's not worth your time. Your flags will have alerted the mod team, and we are generally better equipped to deal with these situations - with various tools and levels of escalation available depending on the severity of the matter.

Comment: I would never leave a mean comment in reply, I know better. That just brings more hurt.

Comment: Thankyou for the confirmation. I'll admit that at the time, I was a bit worked up, but did my best to simply contain the situation (I personally have had other experiences with this sort of thing, both through observation and personal involvement). Since I was feeling a bit hot headed my reply was, as you pointed out, a bit excessive.

Comment: @Ben - your reply definitely wasn't too bad. I was more giving advice for future scenarios in which you or someone does reply to rude comments, rather than saying your comment was out of line or anything.